# How do I chain call functions?

Tags: javascript

Hey guys am new to javascript app development

When i tried this code

```
function name() {
return 5;
}

function anotherone() {
return 3;
}

function horse() {
return 5;
}
```

When i called the function like `console.log(name().anotherone().horse());` ..it throws me error like `undefined not a function`.

Is it possible to call function like `afunction().anotherfunction().anotherfunction1()` in javascript ??

Thanks in advance..

Comment: That is not how this works at all. `.` indicates a property of an object (in this case, a method of an object). You are effectively trying to call `anotherone` as though it were a method of `5`, which it is not.

Comment: No.You can't. What are you trying to do?

Comment: It looks like you want to implement a fluent interface, but method chaining only makes sense when you work with an object. You have just functions though. Are you maybe looking for function composition? What's the overall purpose of this code? How are the functions related? What should the result be? Sure we can come up with some solution that makes it possible to call the functions like this, but whether this is what you really want/need is a different question. You'd have to provide more information if you want to be helped *properly*.

Comment: @FelixKling i just need to execute the 3 functions without an object like ...afunction().anotherfunction().anotherfunction1() ??..is there any way

Comment: Why do you have to do this? What's the point? The functions don't seem to have anything to do with each other.

Comment: @FelixKling yeah i mean can we do like this ?

Comment: As already mentioned a couple of times, no, not with this setup. You are returning **numbers** from the functions and numbers don't have, for example, a `anotherone` or `horse` method. If you change the implementation of your functions, then yes, it's possible.

Answer (score 2):

When you call`name().another(`), this evaluates to `(5).anotherone()`.

`anotherone()` is not a function of the literal 5, which is why you get the error `undefined is not a function`. If you want to chain methods, use a class/object that returns an instance of itself so you can call `myClass.aFunction().anotherfunction()` so the call stack evaluates to `(myClass).anotherfunction()`

Comment: ..i know we can do this by var b = new function() b.afunctionname()..but i just want to know can we do like afunction().anotherfunction().anotherfunction() ?

Comment: only if `afunction()` returns something that `.anotherfunction()` can be called on.

Comment: can you please provide as an example

Comment: as an example of what? Fabian Lauer's answer provides an example of how to do this with objects and Ramy's answer provides an example of how to do this with classes

Comment: I added an answer with an example for you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. Every function but the last in the chain have to return the object containing the function you call next, for example:

```
var obj = {
    foo: function(){ return obj; },
    bar: function(){ return obj; },
    baz: function(){ return 123; }
};

console.log(obj.foo().bar().baz()); // works, logs 123
```

Comment: When i run this i got foo is undefined

Comment: I'm sorry, forgot the object accessor before `foo`. Edited.

Comment: i know this can be done with obj..but what i need is to use function without obj ..

Comment: You're always in an object context in JavaScript. This, and I think that's what you mean, could also be `window` or the context of a function. Instead of returning `obj`, you can return `this`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your syntax.

Look at your functions: the first returns 5, so you're essentially doing `5.anotherone()`. Dot notation is for accessing properties and methods of an object. `anotherone()` is not a method of `5`, so you'll get `undefined is not a function`.

Also, you don't provide any arguments for the functions, so you can't pass anything to them.

You can *kind of* do what you're describing, but you have to go about it a bit differently:

```
function name() {
    return 5;
}

function anotherone(num) {
    return num + 3;
}

function horse(num) {
    return num + 5;
}

console.log(horse(anotherone(name())));
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/AstroCB/T54ng/1/)

Comment: plz see my qus ..i want to do like afunction().anotherfunction().anotherfunction1()

Comment: @user3869069 I understand what you're trying to do, but the only way that that is possible is through Fabian Lauer's answer, for reasons I have described above. You're trying to change the syntax of JavaScript for your own purposes, which is something that you simply cannot do without modifying prototypes.

Answer (score 0):

Read more about [OOP in javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript)

```
var Class = function () {};

Class.prototype = {
    value: 0,
    addOne: function () {
        // do stuff
        this.value++;

        return this;
    },
    addTwo: function () {
        this.value = this.value + 2;

        return this;
    },
    getValue: function () {
        return this.value;
    }
};

var obj = new Class();
// Chaining possible when you return the object at the end of your method
console.log(obj.addOne().addTwo().addOne().getValue()); // returns 4

// Chaining is not possible when you return something else
console.log(obj.addOne().getValue().addOne()); // undefined is not a function
```

Answer (score 0):

Its quiet easy:-

```
function name() {
return 5;
setTimeout(anotherone,0);
}

function anotherone() {
return 3;
setTimeout(horse,0);
}

function horse() {
return 5;
}
```

Now you just need to call the first function and it will call the next one itself.